# How to get the text of an element(<a> by nature) using xPath() in Mocha with Selenium environment?

Tags: selenium, xpath, mocha.js

```
<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
   <li>
      <a class="user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message" href="/profile/">saswat@matrixnmedia.com</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="http://saswatr3.ouh.co/main/account/help.php">
      <i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="log-out" href="/logout">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
       Log out
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The first `<a>` tag contains an email id which varies based on the login session.

I want to get the text of the `<a>` tag using `xPath()` in Mocha.

I am writing this code snippet, but I think I am doing it wrong.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message']")).then(function(elements_arr1)
{
   if(elements_arr1.length > 0)
   {
      console.log(elements_arr1);
   }
});
```

I am getting the details like this.

```
[ { driver_:
     { session_: [Object],
       executor_: [Object],
       flow_: [Object],
       fileDetector_: null,
       quit: [Function] },
    id_:
     { closure_uid_36922274: 489,
       flow_: [Object],
       stack_: null,
       parent_: null,
       callbacks_: null,
       state_: 'fulfilled',
       handled_: false,
       pendingNotifications_: false,
       value_: [Object] } } ]
```

But I need the text, i.e. saswat@matrixnmedia.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Mocha but I can point you in the right direction...

`.findElements` returns some kind of collection. You are doing the equivalent of logging an array, not an element of the array, but the array itself. That's why you are getting weird results.

You can do a couple things...

1) Access the element in the collection that you care about. In Java you would do

```
List<WebElement> stuff = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input"));
String text = stuff.get(0).getText(); // gets the innerText of the first (0th) element of the List.
```

2) If you always want the first element, just use `.findElement()` (not Element**s**())

OK... now you have the right element and you want to get the text from it... use `.getText()` on the element

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input")).getText(); // returns the text of the first INPUT element
```

If it were me, I would avoid XPath like the plague... it's slow and prone to breaking (and confusing, at least to me). I think this should work for you

```
String email = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.user-name")).getText();
```

The CSS Selector `a.user-name` means find an `A` tag with the class (.) `user-name`

[CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)